# How to set different validation constraints depending on http method type?

Tags: validation, go

Say I have a struct:

```
type Invoice struct {
    ID     *int64        
    Number *int64        
    Date   *time.Time
}
```

I receive it as JSON, unmarshal it and before using it further I want to validate its fields. For example, I'd like to make Number and Date fields mandatory for POST request and let them be optional for PUT requests. Is there a **good** way of doing that? Are there any validators that allow different validation rules for the same struct type which you can switch depending on the use case?

Comment: If you require a data, check if the field is not `nil`. What's the question?

Comment: @icza, that's ugly if you have a lot of big structs.

Comment: The standard lib (`encoding/json`) does not support making / marking fields mandatory. You need a 3rd party lib for that.

Comment: @icza, yes, that I know. That's basically where my question comes from. I'm not able to make the 3rd party validators apply different rules depending on the method type. Was thinking maybe there's a way of doing it with or without the validators.

Answer (score 0):

I do not consider this a good solution but you may find your way through my suggestion.

You could use tags in your struct and then inspect it using reflection.

```
type Invoice struct {
    ID     *int64 `required`       
    Number *int64        
    Date   *time.Time
}
```

and then

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Invoice struct {
    ID     *int64 `required`        
    Number *int64        
    Date   *time.Time
}

...

t := reflect.TypeOf(myInvoice)
id, _ := t.FieldByName("ID")
if id.Tag == "required" && ...
```

However, I would try to avoid using reflection in cases like this since it is not a good use case.

An overview of tags can be found here:

https://medium.com/golangspec/tags-in-golang-3e5db0b8ef3e